# Extract 2 non-consecutive strings and always sort them in desired way

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

*I'm finishing my regex project in google sheets and this last question I have for it. Hope you can help.*

I have a column, in which one cell may or may not contain multiple strings.

**This is an example of it (start position):**

[image]

Now I want to extract the following values:

- Team (A)
- Team B
- Team (A) Team B

**Desired end result image:**

[image]

**I want to check for all 3 possible values, and always sort them with Team (A) as a priority. In case the initial cell (C column) is empty, the result is empty.**

I tried this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"Team \(A\)|Team B|[Team \(A\) "&" Team B]"),IF(C2="","")))
```

**Problems I have:**

- Don't know how to give priority :/
- Don't know how to give them sorting order :/

*All help welcome, thank you.*

Comment: are there a line breaks in C column?

Comment: Yes, there are line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "(Team \(A\))")&CHAR(10))&
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "(Team B)")), "\n$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing :)))))))))  I have no words, kudos man for this beauty!